# Copy Sheet1 in Active Workbook to Sheet 2 in Workbook named in Cell of Active Workbook Sheet 2

Tags: excel

I have a series of Workbooks that I continually need to copy Sheet1 of a workbook to Sheet2 of the new workbook. The names of the Workbooks will advance in number (name_May2011_2, name_May2011_3, name_May2011_5). The digit on the end will change, not necessarily in sequence. I have code that allows me to list the active workbooks in a new sheet. I need to reference a cell in that sheet as the name of the Workbook as the destination top copy. My code is as follows so far:

[code]
Sub Copy_Merge()

```
'Declare variables and data types
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Single, j As Single


 
'Create a new worksheet and save to object ws
Set Ws = Sheets.Add
 
'Go through open workbooks
For j = 1 To Workbooks.Count
 
    'Save workbook name to cell A1 and downwards
    Range("A1").Cells(j, 1) = Workbooks(j).Name
     
    'Iterate through worksheets in given workbook
    For i = 1 To Workbooks(j).Sheets.Count
   
            'Save worksheet names to cell B1 and cells further right
            Range("A1").Cells(j, i + 1) = Workbooks(j).Sheets(i).Name
 
    'Continue with next worksheet
    Next i
 
'Continue with next workbook
Next j
```

'This is the part I'm having issues with
'I need to set variable in cell A2 of Sheet 2 of Active Workbook as a string
'and use that string as the Workbook destination name

```
Dim SB As Workbook
Dim Ss As Worksheet

Set SB = ThisWorkbook
Set Ss = ThisWorkbook.Sheet("Sheet2")
Set MyToday = SB.Ss.Range("A2").Value 'name of destination workbook


Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks(MyToday).Sheets(3)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2"
On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub
[/code]

I've been working on this for a few days, I'm relatively new to writing macro's, and I'm at my whit's end. Can someone help with this code or suggest a better code to use?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the target workbook's name from cell "A2" of "Sheet2" of your current workbook and use it to assign the respective workbook to an object, you could use:

```
Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook   ' Your SB
Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet ' Your Ss

Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetWorkbookName As String
Dim TargetSheetName As String

Set SourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set SourceWorksheet = SourceWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")           ' the "s" in "Sheets" is important to access the Workbook's Sheet-Collection

TargetWorkbookName = SourceWorksheet.Range("A2").Value          ' TargetWorkbookName is of type "String", thus "Set" is not allowed
Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks(TargetWorkbookName)
TargetSheetName = SourceWorksheet.Range("B2").Value
Set TargetWorksheet = TargetWorkbook.Sheets(TargetSheetName)
```